# How to allow for angular Factory object to finish construction before initializing controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's the dealio:

I have multiple steps of an online form. Each step is defined by the same template, and the inputs are defined by members of a static object defined elsewhere in the app.

Initially, the app was built with a HUGE main controller (1200 lines-ish) and the use of the $scope prototype chain was relied on HEAVILY.

It felt very wrong to me, so I am attempting to pull all the cross-controller functionality into a factory.

Unfortunately, this broke pretty much everything. WINNING!

Anyhow, each step has its own controller. Which looks like this(greatly simplified):

```
angular.module('app').controller('Step1Controller', ['$rootScope','$scope', 
'$timeout', 'jsonService', 'StepFactory', function ($rootScope, $scope, 
$timeout, jsonService, StepFactory) {

    var vm = this;

    StepFactory.doAThingAndWhatnot(1);

    vm.aVariable = StepFactory.iAmAnObject.aVariable;

    vm.aSecondVariable = StepFactory.iAmAnObject.aSecondVariable;

    vm.ohAnArray = StepFactory.iAmAnObject.ohAnArray;

    vm.iDoThings = function() {
         // Things being done 
    }
}]);
```

Below is the StepFactory. All the functions inside it serve to ultimately modify the `iAmAnObject` members, which should then be passed down to the controllers for the steps (seen above). There are network requests within the StepFactory functions.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to wait for ALL of these functions to finish what they're doing before the step controller is initialized, then have the `iAmAnObject` made available to the scope of the step controller.

Here's the factory (greatly simplified):

```
angular.module('app').factory('StepFactory', ['$q', '$location', '$routeParams',
'$rootScope', 'jsonService', function($q, $location, $routeParams, $rootScope, 
jsonService) {

    var iAmAnObject = {};

    iAmAnObject.aVariable = '';

    iAmAnObject.aSecondVariable = '';

    iAmAnObject.ohAnArray = [];

    function doAThingAndWhatnot(index) {
        // does some things and whatnot using all the other functions
        // in this here factory
    }

    function yetMoreThingsToBeDone() {
        // lots of things being done in here but what can you do?
    }

    function ohLookMoreThingsBeingDone() {
        // I'm doing things, don't bother me
    }

    function moreDoingOfStuff() {
       // the amount of stuff I'm doing...I can't even
    }

    function lastStuffToDo() {
       // The stuff. It's being done.
    }

    function okILied() {
       // little bit more stuff to do here.
    }

    return {
        iAmAnObject: iAmAnObject,
        doAThingAndWhatnot: doAThingAndWhatnot,
        yetMoreThingsToBeDone: yetMoreThingsToBeDone,
        ohLookMoreThingsBeingDone: ohLookMoreThingsBeingDone,
        moreDoingOfStuff: moreDoingOfStuff,
        lastStuffToDo: lastStuffToDo,
        okILied: okILied
    }
}]);
```

Yes, I've looked into the `resolve` functionality in the route handlers, but I simply can't figure out exactly how to configure the promise within the factory.

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing it or  you left it out, but it doesn't look like you're executing any of the functions from the factory, just declaring them.

Comment: Yup, in my attempt to cut out all the unnecessary fluff, I took that out as well. What's happening is the `doAThingAndWhatnot` function in the factory is using all the other functions in the factory to modify the `iAmAnObject` variable. I have edited my code snippets. I hope that helps you help me haha.

Comment: Why not put `doAThingAndWhatnot` inside the factory so that it modifies `iAmAnObject` before it is returned?

Comment: @Lucas if I'm not mistaken, that's exactly what my code is doing. And it works. As far as `iAmAnObject` being modified as it should be.

The problem lies in that the scope variables in each step controller (which should reflect the latest variables from the factory object) are initialized before the factory is done with all its work.

So I end up with some scope variables that are empty once the page loads even though I can check the factory object and see that all the variables have been set properly.

Comment: Don't assign primitives in the controller. Simply pass the object to variable in controller `vm.iAmAnObject= StepFactory.iAmAnObject` . Then use the various property names in view and view will update if they get changed. You basically let angular manage all the watches that way and don't have a whole bunch of extra variables in the controller